# Função "Se" do Excel dando problema ao verificar se todos os valores são verdadeiros

Tags: microsoft-excel

Utilizei a função "Se" e a "Cont.se", porém eu queria que a função "Se" verificasse  se todos os valores da sequencia de (C69:C73) forem ="500", no entanto ao verificar o penúltimo valor ele considera que todos os valores são "500" sendo que o ultimo valor é "400" e logo após ele executa a contagem de apenas os números "500" na sequencia (B69:B73) referente a função "Cont.se", eu queria que a função "Se" considerasse se todos os valores forem "500" da sequencia de (C69:C73) e depois executasse a fórmula, porque a função "Se" não considera se todos os valores forem "500"?? sendo que o ultimo é "400" ?? pois no caso deveria retorna "Falso" porque todos os valores não são "500", ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
=SE(C69:C73=500;CONT.SE(B69:B73;B72);0)
```

Answer (score -1):

então não sei o porque deste erro. Mas acredito que se você tiver que resolver algo muito urgente tenho uma solução um pouco mais trabalhosa.

A solução é a seguinte:
Contar quantas valores de C69:C73 = 500 com a fórmula   - > =CONT.SE(C69:C73;500)

Contar a quantidade de números que existe no intervalo C69:C73 com a fórmula - >=CONT.NÚM(C69:C73)

Contar a quantidade de células vazias no intervalo C69:C73 com a fórmula -> =CONTAR.VAZIO(C69:C73)

Depois somar a quantidade de células comparadas somando F73 + F74 conforme imagem.

Depois comparar **QUANTIDADE DE NÚMEROS = 500(F72)** com **QUANTIDADE DE CÉLULAS COMPARADAS(F75)**  FÓRMULA -> =SE(F72=F75;"IGUAL";"DIFERENTE")

Por ultimo analisar Se a Célular **I72 = "IGUAL"** se for igual contar a quantidade de vezes que aparece o 500 no intervalo B69:B73  com a fórmula - > =SE(I72="IGUAL";CONT.SE(B69:B73;500);"NÃO CONTOU")[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu não sei o que está acontecendo com meu Excel, agora ele não quer comparar nenhum valor, agora ele afirma que tudo é verdadeiro

Comment: Sendo que apenas um valor da sequencia tem o "500" ele já considera e executa a fórmula no verdadeiro. Já estou de saco cheio...

Comment: Vc tentou usar minha fórmula no seu?? para ver se acontece o mesmo, ?

Comment: Sim aconteceu o mesmo que o seu.

Comment: Fiz uma fórmula para forçar mais ele dar verdadeiro, mas mesmo assim continua dando verdadeiro mesmo não sendo, ''=SE(E(C69:C73=500);CONT.NÚM(B69:B73)-CONT.SE(B69:B73;"<>500");0)''

Comment: Com apenas três valores de "500" e dois sendo "400" ele já considera verdadeiro